# AssertionError: expected Promise{…} to equal 1

Tags: truffle, testing, mocha, chai

Code:

```
    describe("uploading post", async () => {

        let result, postCounter
        const hash = "whatever"

        before(async () => {
            result = await myContract.upload(hash, "description", "whatever", {from: accounts[0]})
            postCounter = myContract.postCounter()
        })

33      it("deployed successfully!", async () => {
34            assert.equal(postCounter, 1)
35         const event = result.logs[0].args
36          assert.equal(event.id.toNumber(), postCounter)
37          assert.equal(event.imageHash, hash)
            assert.equal(event.description, "description")
            assert.equal(event.author, accounts[0])

            await myContract.upload("", "description", "whatever", {from: accounts[0]}).should.be.rejected;
            await myContract.upload("hash", "", "whatever", {from: accounts[0]}).should.be.rejected;
        })
    })
```

Error:

```
   uploading post
         deployed successfully!:
     AssertionError: expected Promise{…} to equal 1
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\test.js:34:20)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```js
assert.equal(await postCounter, 1)
```

Or, to debug it:

```js
const postCounterResult = await postCounter;
console.log("postCounterResult: ", postCounterResult);
assert.equal(postCounterResult, 1);
```

Also, for properly testing functions that return promises, consider using the `chai-as-promised` library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised

https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised

https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

I used it recently to test asynchronous blockchain related code.